# CSS's equivalent to JavaScript's document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can CSS write HTML code, analogously to how JavaScript's document.write can? Thanks

Comment: Do not use `document.write`.

Comment: Apple's equivalent to orange.

Comment: @iambriansreed. Does this question considered to be a "real question"?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JimG. The reason I ask is because I'd like a CSS stylesheet that writes some information on everything it styles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really.

It has [the `content` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content), but that's as close as it gets.

Content is the job of HTML. Leave CSS for presentation and JavaScript for logic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The reason I ask is because I'd like a CSS stylesheet that writes some information on everything it styles.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write HTML code processed as HTML, but content generation can be done, and is useful in a limited scope for optional content.

Example: you have link elements, some of which point to pdf files. You want CSS to write out the string "(pdf)" at the end of each link whose destination ends with a .pdf extension. You write a rule to append your string to the ::after pseudo-element based on a substring matching attribute selector.

```
a[href$=".pdf"]::after {content:"(pdf)";}
```

This is unlikely to be useful for mandatory content, as browser support is not complete.

Comment: A note: ::after is technically proper for a pseudo-element, but some IE browsers will choke on it, so in a real implementation use :after for compatibility. Added as a comment, since this isn't really important for the solution.